# Is there a utility to list entry points in an object (.o) file?

Tags: c++, gcc, entry-point

Is there a utility that will list the entry points in an object (.o) file? In this case produced by gcc on current debian linux.  As 'ar t libxxx.a' will list the files, so i would like to see the entries in a file.

Comment: Do you mean like `nm`? Not sure what you mean by "entry-points", since that tends to be ONE place [for example `main` or `dllmain` or `start` or something like that, where the code "enters" an executable]

Comment: Which platform?  Which compiler?  Which OS?  Object files can differ by compiler and platform.

Comment: Yes! nm is what I was looking for.  I've been away from unix for a long time and couldn't remember if there was or not.  Of course you can have multiple entries (extern functions) in files intended to be included in a library.   Thank you.